# Time complexity of pushing elements using Object.values(test[i])

Tags: javascript, loops, object, time-complexity, big-o

What would be the time complexity of doing something like:

```
// assume all values are primitives
const result = [];
for(const test of tests){
  result.push(Object.values(test));
}
```

I know that `Object.keys` is O(n) and thus assume the same for `Object.values`, which makes me believe this is O(n²), but I'm looking for a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

since: [enter link description here](https://dev.to/himanshukanojiya/big-o-time-complexities-of-javascript-object-arrays-and-their-methods-5gpk)

> Object.values Method: Happens in O(N)

and you have a nested "for", your believes are right and your algorithm have a O(n²) time complexity resolution

Comment: A nested for-loop doesn't by definition mean it is `O(n²)`, does it? Adding extra elements to `tests` doesn't necessarily mean that `Object.values(test)` returns more values.

Comment: @Ivar you are absolutely right and Typically (but not always) one loop nested in another will cause O(n²). But having that he is iterating over 2 enumerable objects the worst scenario is O(n²).